# In Python how do I correct this Module Not Found Error

Tags: python, module, compiler-errors

I have the following module structure in my Administrator project folder

StockController.py (in the root project folder)

then in a package called Utilities I have the following two modules

1. ExcelManipulator.py
2. StockPurchaseInfo.py

Relevant Code from each module as as follows:

StockController.py

```
from Utilities.ExcelManipulator 
import ExcelManipulatorClass
```

ExcelManipulator.py

```
from StockPurchaseInfo import StockInfoClass
class ExcelManipulatorClass:
```

StockPurchaseInfo.py

```
class StockInfoClass:
```

When running the StockController module I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Administrator\StockController.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Utilities.ExcelManipulator import ExcelManipulatorClass
 File "d:\Administrator\Utilities\ExcelManipulator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from StockPurchaseInfo import StockInfoClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StockPurchaseInfo'
```

However when I run the ExcelManipulator.py module I dont get the error (it is able to find the StockPurchaseInfo module) why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `__init__.py` in your Utilities directory ?

And in your ExcelManipulator, you've to do this :
`from Utilities.StockPurchaseInfo import StockInfoClass` (or  `from .StockPurchaseInfo import StockInfoClass` to import relatively)

If you run your programm from the root of your project (and you should do so), modules path are defined from it (from the root of the project), so if you're doing `from StockPurchaseInfo import StockInfoClass` then python is looking for an StockPurchaseInfo.py in you're root project.

Comment: thank you, that did the trick. I am a bit confused though as since Python 3.3, __init__.py is no longer required to define directories as importable Python packages???